# Is Direct Airside Transit Visa required at London for an Indian for a flight from Mumbai to USA via London

Tags: indian-citizens, datv

I have a flight from Mumbai to USA via Heathrow, London (LHR) and a valid US student visa. I will be reaching London on 7th August at 6 pm and have a connecting flight to USA on 8th August at 9 am. As such, a layover of 15 hrs including a night stay (change of date). Both my flights are from LHR only, also I do not have any plan to come out from the airport.

On reading - point 2 of 'Transiting without a Visa' on GOV.UK website, it says- 'before midnight on the day after you arrive'; which is ambiguous that the midnight is of next day of arrival or the same day.

Please guide me that in the above scenario, will Direct Airside Transit Visa or any other visa be required at London (LHR)?

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. Your question is very similar to one we already have. Please read the question and answers in the suggested duplicate. If that does not answer your question, edit your question to point out why your case is different.

Comment: That is not at all ambiguous; only one meaning makes sense.